# Calling a php function by an jquery ajax request and updating a div by the return object

Tags: php, jquery

I have a div and some labels in it. The labels show information by a given php object's properties.

I want to update that object by an ajax request in every 3 seconds and then update the div by the newest object's properties.

How can I do that ? Actually I am curious about calling the function and reading return object's properties in the jquery ajax function. I can handle other parts.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` something like this:

```
var interval = setInterval(yourAjaxFun, 3000);
```

where the function `yourAjaxFun` does updating you need.

You can clear the interval any time later using:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

---

From your php code, you can use `json_encode` function on your object to return it as JSON so that you can parse the returned response using jQuery JSON parsing function eg `parseJSON`